# Does morphia have cursors and foreign keys and constraints for mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Does morphia have cursors and foreign keys and constraints for mongodb, or at least functionality for these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are cursors, and constraints (like unique indexes) but that is about it.

For the rest, it does not support these as the server doesn't support these. You can build your own validation for this but without server support it will be hard to cover all the corner cases.